# Attempt to change jQuery version caused White Screen of Death

Tags: functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm working on a client's WP installation, and I'm attempting to replace the default jQuery library included with WordPress to a newer version. I inserted the following script into the site's functions.php file, but I was greeted with the "White Screen of Death" upon save:

```
function modify_jquery_version() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery',
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', false, '2.1.s');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? Is there a better way to replace jQuery than via the code above? It worked on my personal sandbox installation.

Comment: Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: you shouldn't re-register jquery, it can cause compatability issues with plugins and core

Comment: So then what's my option? The code I need to install requires a newer version of jQuery.